# I have to dispay more than 20 thousand records using javascript but it takes lot of time

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

Hence planned to display 500 records in 1 page and next 500 records in next when next button is clicked.How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Where are these records coming from? What's going on sever-side?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=pagination+tutorial

Comment: even 500 at a time seems fairly excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for lazy loading

What you need to do, you can load the records according to screen and when user scroll down then load next records. Just like a Facebook doing so, here is look some links

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3738616/Lazy-Loading-the-ASPNET-AJAX-TabContainer-Control.htm

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/408/lazy-loading/

Answer (score 0):

You should be paging the data server-side and only sending one page worth of data at a time. There are a lot of ways to do that, but the important thing is to keep track of what page you're on, and probably only query one page worth of records from the database on each server request. It's also important that you not dump the whole thing in the ViewState, which has to be passed back and forth between requests.

The other issue is how much data fits into these 500-record pages. If it's a lot (like images or something), you're only going to be able to streamline the process so much without looking for ways to reduce the amount of data in the page (e.g. using thumbnail images, etc).

Finally, consider something like AJAX to allow you to avoid having to rebind the whole page every time.